# Local Java application to interact with Google Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-client, objectify

I am currently attempting to create an automated data export from an existing Google Datastore "Kind" to output to a json file.

I'm having trouble finding a suitable example that allows me to simply pull specific entities from the Datastore and push them out into an output file.

All the examples and documentation I've found assume I am creating an app-engine project to interface with the Datastore. The program I need to create would have to be local to sit on a server and query the Datastore to pull down the data.

Is my approach possible? Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

But you'll have to use one of the generic [Cloud Datastore Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries), not the GAE-specific one(s). You'll still need a GAE app, but you don't have to run your code in it, see [Dependency on App Engine application](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#dependency_on_gae_name_short_application).

You could also use one of the REST/RPC/GQL APIs, see [APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis).

Some of the referenced docs contain examples as well.

Comment: Dan much thanks for your response. I'm going to read the "Dependency" link in order to understand the need for the GAE app. Would you recommend going the API route instead?

Comment: The dependency is pretty basic - pretty much just provisioning of the datastore itself, nothing to worry about. I can't give a recommendation, I only accessed the datastore from a GAE app, the answer is based on documentation only.